# LD_LIBRARY_PATH cleared when logging in through xrdp

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, bash, centos

## Background:

I am currently working in a Linux Virtual Machine on some Java plugins that I install into Eclipse by placing them into the **/opt/eclipse/dropins** folder. My plugins need to support both CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 VMs (shouldn't be a big deal since they are written in Java and both flavors of CentOS have Java 1.8.0 installed). My plugins build and install just fine on both OSs. I see them in Eclipse and can interact with them as expected.

The VMs I need to support can either be local to my machine (opened with VMWare Player/Workstation) or hosted on a cloud server. We use Windows Remote Desktop to get into the cloud VMs through xrdp on the Linux server.

## Problem:

One of my plugins needs **nddsjava.so** from **/opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3/lib/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2**.

On both local VMs (CentOS 6 and 7), I can just set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in an /etc/profile.d script so that any user that logs in can get the path to the required C++ library.

On CentOS 7 cloud VMs, however, when this plugin is invoked, I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nddsjava in java.library.path`. This happens **only** when opening Eclipse via the Linux menus. If I open a terminal and start Eclipse from there, the plugin can find the C++ library (because my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in my /bin/bash terminal). I did a little digging and found out that running `chmod g-s /usr/bin/ssh-agent` fixes the issue when opening Eclipse from the Linux menus (yes I understand that the chmod opens a security vulnerability. I am willing to look past this).

On CentOS 6 cloud VMs, I have never gotten the plugin to find the C++ library. LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to get wiped when signing in through **xrdp** and for whatever reason, CentOS 6 appears to be explicitly not sourcing any of the profile scripts in the main top-level gnome-session process, which means other processes spawned from the GUI will not have LD_LIBRARY_PATH either.

I have also tried adding `-Djava.library.path` to my `eclipse.ini` file with no luck. It will fail on the next C++ library needed even though it lives in the same directory: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3/lib/x64Linux3gcc4.8.2/libnddsjava.so: libnddsc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

## Question:

Is there a single place that I can set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH for all flavors of Linux I am attempting to support (local CentOS 6, xrdp CentOS 6, local CentOS 7, and xrdp CentOS 7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** When I say cloud VM below, I mean server hosted VM in which I Windows-Remote-Desktopped into via *xrdp*.

[This](https://serverfault.com/a/724028/413371) answer from server fault worked for me in the CentOS 6 cloud VM. The CentOS 7 cloud VM did not have the `startwm.sh` script in `/etc/xrdp`. Instead, it lived in `/usr/libexec/xrdp` and did not contain the `xinitrc` lines (referenced in the server fault link) causing the issue in the CentOS 6 cloud VM. Something else must be wiping the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in the CentOS 7 cloud VM, so I still needed to perform `chmod g-s /usr/bin/ssh-agent` to allow my `/etc/profile.d` script to be invoked on startup.